# Messaging apps no longer work right after last update - Galaxy S8 Plus

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I updated 2 days ago.  Samsung Galaxy S8+    REV1.0

Now I no longer receive message notifications on my lock screen
The field to set the individual SMS/Message tone has disappeared as well
and ALL messages have the SAME sounds now. 
I have no longer the option to  "Add a field" in the message apps either

Notifications are all turned on!

I use the Android message app and the Verizon message app.

Answer (score 0):

It is Samsung's Oreo update.  They removed the feature.  Complain to them. The more that complain the more chance the will fix it.